# Creating a login page using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, servlets

I am working on an online banking project. The issue when the user enters the user name and password on the page then the validation is done on another page and i want to repopulate the start page with an error message. What is the method i need to follow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into spring-security. It is easy to set up an error message with that framework. However I'm not sure if it's safe enough for online banking.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
    <p>Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br />
    <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />.</p>
</c:if>
```

c refers to the JSTL core library.

Comment: Don't wanna sound rude, but I do hope so :)

Comment: I guess he didn't specify, about using Spring Framework.. in the question !

Comment: @Ratna: I think Mark said `You might want to look into spring-security` like a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

put the message into your session object, on the 1st page check if that thing you put in there is not null, if not null display it

Comment: why in the session object? wouldn't it be enough to add the attribute to the request?

Comment: i assumed the 1st page was opened by making another request.